# Why does the float-right element not go all the way to the top?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I know that this happens, but would like clarification as to why, as I'm trying to get a better understanding of the float mechanic

Given this HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner first">1</div>
  <div class="inner second">2</div>
  <div class="inner third">3</div>
</div>
```

And this CSS

```
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.first, .second {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.third {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
}
```

The third div does not float all the way to the top right, but aligns with the second div

[image: Example]

I know that this happens but I would like a more specific explanation as to why (based on what rule)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question, I have seen some people having difficulty understanding this. As per your question, I feel you want to align '3' to the top-right in the box. Your inner is 500 * 500, and your first and second is 300*300, since it cannot fit total of 600, the second one will go below first one. Then there is a space of 200 for third one. It will take next 200 space (next to second one) and the space above is not utilized. To get desired output, what you want is shift 3 up as shown below so that the space of 200 in the top right is utilized first.

May be this can help you:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner third alg">3</div>
  <div class="inner first">1</div>
  <div class="inner second ">2</div>
  </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.first, .second {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.alg{
  text-align: right;
}

.third {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
}
```

[image]

I hope this makes things more clear to you now. If not comment below, I can explain with some more examples.

Comment: @MadOgre: Hope this is helpful. Sorry didn't crop image properly. But run it in your editor, it should give your desired output :)

Comment: Thank you, that was very clear and very detailed. I didn't realize that the flow order is still preserved (I was assuming float ignores the main flow completely)

Comment: @MadOgre: Great. I am glad, it was helpful. You can accept the answer.

Comment: @MadOgre: The flow order will always be preserved.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the [float rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-rules) say

> 5. The [outer top](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#outer-edge) of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top of any [block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes) or [floated](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats) box generated by an element earlier in the source document.

Since there is not enough space at the right of `.first`, `.second` is placed below. But then `.third` can't be placed above `.second`, even if it fits in the available space left by `.first`.

Comment: Thank you! Very awesome of you to provide exact link to the rules!

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the page flow order. When you float an element you are not completely removing it from the flow order of the page but instead specifying that it should position itself to the left or the right of an element. By floating div three to the right you are not removing it from flow entirely like when you position a div absolutely.

In your example div one and two's net width is wider than the parent wrapper. This means they cannot rest inline so they stack. Div three positions to the right of the element that comes before it (div two) but is still influenced by the flow order and sits below div one.

Comment: Note floats are out-of-flow. It's just that they are able to shrink line boxes and affect the size of formatting context root ancestors, unlike absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: Would It be more accurate if it said, "when you float an element you do not remove its order of flow?" Your answer to this question is a good answer with a good reference.